# Aligning a float:left div to center?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a group of images display horizontally across the page. Each image has a few link below it so I need to put a container around each image/link-group.

The closest I have gotten to what I want is putting them in divs that float:left. The problem is I want the containers to align center not left. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

use `display:inline-block;` instead of float

you can't centre floats, but inline-blocks centre as if they were text, so on the outer overall container  of your "row" - you would set `text-align: center;` then for each image/caption container (it's those which would be `inline-block;`) you can re-align the text to left if you require

Comment: Just in case anyone is struggling with the spaces that appear in between the elements, remove the the whitespace in your code by defining your elements like '<img></img><img></img>' or '<img></img><!-- Comment --><img></img>'.

Comment: Or set the parent element `font-size:0` and restore it on the child. Or use `letter-spacing:-.31em` on the parent and `letter-spacing:0` on the child.

Comment: @Baumr Use flexbox instead. [There is a example below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27108510/63849).

Comment: you may need to add `vertical-align:middle` while using `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 50):

CSS [Flexbox is well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) these days. [Go here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a good tutorial on flexbox.

This works fine in all newer browsers:

```css
#container {
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap:       wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block {
  width:              150px;
  height:             150px;
  background-color:   #cccccc;
  margin:             10px;        
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">1</div>    
  <div class="block">2</div>    
  <div class="block">3</div>    
  <div class="block">4</div>    
  <div class="block">5</div>        
</div>
```

Some may ask why not use display: inline-block? For simple things it is fine, but if you got complex code within the blocks, the layout may not be correctly centered anymore. Flexbox is more stable than float left.

Comment: This works for centering horizontally.  How about centering vertically as well?

Comment: To center vertically give the container a height (e.g. height: 500px;) and add align-items: center;

Answer (score 9):

try it like this:

```
  <div id="divContainer">
    <div class="divImageHolder">
    IMG HERE
    </div>
    <div class="divImageHolder">
    IMG HERE
    </div>
    <div class="divImageHolder">
    IMG HERE
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
    </div>

    <style type="text/css">
    #divContainer { margin: 0 auto; width: 800px; }
    .divImageHolder { float:left; }
    .clear { clear:both; }
    </style>
```

Comment: Posting just code without an explanation is discouraged. Also, `type="text/css"` on a `<style>` tag is superfluous and hasn't been necessary for several years now and applying a clear class to a <br> tag is an antipattern.

Comment: @StephenMIrving you replied 10 years after the person initially replied so standards are completely different.

Answer (score 8):

Just wrap floated elements in a `<div>` and give it this CSS:

```
.wrapper {

display: table;
margin: auto;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this what you're looking for - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

CSS:

```
#container {
  display:                 flex;
  flex-wrap:               wrap;
  justify-content:         center;
}

.block {
  width:              150px;
  height:             150px;
  margin:             10px;        
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">1</div>    
  <div class="block">2</div>    
  <div class="block">3</div>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.contentWrapper {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.repeater {
    height: 9em;
    width: 9em;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.2em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Posting just code without an explanation is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @StephenMIrving c/p same comment with downvote spam also discouraged. Question is: "Aligning a float:left div to center?" and given answer with classes "contentWrapper" and "repeater" is pretty self-explanatory. This is not an answer to a complex algorithm question with code only content. I would suggest you to analyze your judgement before auto botting/spamming code only answers with downvote + same comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Downloads</title>

<style>
.download-container{
        width:90%;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        border:0px;
        padding:20px;
    }
    .download-cell{
        vertical-align:center;
        height:100px;
        width:340px;
        border:1px solid black;
        border-radius:8px;
        font-size:24px;
        font-color:black;
        z-index:2;
        margin:20px;
        background:white;
        color:black;
        display:inline-block;
        margin:20px;
        padding-top:20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!--DOWNLOADS-->
<div class="download-container">
<br>
    <div class="download-cell">
        <a target="_blank" class="module" href="http://www.woocommerce.com">
        <img src="Images/woo.png" style="width:60px; height:60px;" />
        WooCommerce
        </a>
    </div>
        
    <div class="download-cell">
        <a target="_blank" class="module" href="http://magento.com">
        <img src="Images/magento.png" style="width:60px; height:60px;" />
        MAGENTO
        </a>
    </div>  
        
    <div class="download-cell">
        <a target="_blank" class="module" href="http://www.lightspeedhq.com">
        <img src="Images/lightspeed.png" style="width:60px; height:60px;" />
        LIGHTSPEED
        </a>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="download-cell">
        <a target="_blank" class="module" href="http://www.shopify.com">
        <img src="Images/shopify.png" style="width:60px; height:60px;" />
        SHOPIFY
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="download-cell">
        <a target="_blank" class="module" href="http://opencart.com">
        <img src="Images/opencart.png" style="width:60px; height:60px;" />
        OPENCART
        </a>
    </div>  
        
    <div class="download-cell">
        <a target="_blank" class="module" href="http://www.prestashop.com">
        <img src="Images/prestashop.png" style="width:60px; height:60px;" />
        PRESTASHOP
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="download-cell">
        <a target="_blank" class="module" href="http://www.wix.com">
        <img src="Images/wix.png" style="width:60px; height:60px;" />
        WIX eCommerce
        </a>
    </div>                                          
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posting just code without an explanation is strongly discouraged.